# Creating a Lua Table from a const char **

Tags: c++, lua, lua-table

I have a `const char **` which is going to be of varying lengths, but I want to create a Lua array from the `const char **`.

My`const char **` is something like this

```
arg[0]="Red"
arg[1]="Purple"
arg[2]="Yellow"
```

I need to convert this array to a global table in Lua, but I'm not sure about how to go about this as I'm not very good at manipulating Lua.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int main()
{
   char* arg[3] = {
      "Red",
      "Purple",
      "Yellow" };

   //create lua state
   Lua_state* L = luaL_newstate();

   // create the table for arg
   lua_createtable(L,3,0);
   int table_index = lua_gettop(L);

   for(int i =0; i<3; ++i )
   {
      // get the string on Lua's stack so it can be used
      lua_pushstring(L,arg[i]);

      // this could be done with lua_settable, but that would require pushing the integer as well
      // the string we just push is removed from the stack
      // notice the index is i+1 as lua is ones based
      lua_rawseti(L,table_index,i+1);
   }

   //now put that table we've been messing with into the globals
   //lua will remove the table from the stack leaving it empty once again
   lua_setglobal(L,"arg");
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the answer, this is pretty easy.
I understand how the tables are structured now.